# Fill void parameters in code behind from html page

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to make tablecells appear when the user hovers over the image.(Basically displaying a tooltip about that image) But I can't seem to send the parameters to my serverside.

HTML & CSS

```css
body{
    background-image: url(Images/Background_Home.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}
.HomeNavImage:hover{
    opacity: .5;
}
.HomeNavImage{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.HomeNav{
    height: 15.7vh;
    padding: 0;
}
#Tooltip1,#Tooltip2,#Tooltip3,#Tooltip4,#Tooltip5,#Tooltip6{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="HomeNavTable">
        <tr><td class="HomeNav"><a href="Home.aspx"><img class="HomeNavImage" src="Images/Home.png" alt="Use a browser that supports images!" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(1)" runat="server" /></a></td><td id="Tooltip1">Home</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="HomeNav"><a href="Forum.aspx"><img class="HomeNavImage" src="Images/Forum.png" alt="Use a browser that supports images!" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(2)" runat="server" /></a></td><td id="Tooltip2">Forum</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="HomeNav"><a href="Project.aspx"><img class="HomeNavImage" src="Images/Project.png" alt="Use a browser that supports images!" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(3)" runat="server" /></a></td><td id="Tooltip3">Project</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="HomeNav"><a href="Contact.aspx"><img class="HomeNavImage" src="Images/Contact.png" alt="Use a browser that supports images!" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(4)" runat="server" /></a></td><td id="Tooltip4">Contact</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="HomeNav"><a href="Store.aspx"><img class="HomeNavImage" src="Images/Store.png" alt="Use a browser that supports images!" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(5)" runat="server" /></a></td><td id="Tooltip5">Store</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="HomeNav"><a href="Patreon.aspx"><img class="HomeNavImage" src="Images/Patreon.png" alt="Use a browser that supports images!" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(6)" runat="server" /></a></td><td id="Tooltip6">Donate</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Code behind

```
private void DisplayTooltip(int ID){
        HtmlTableCell Tooltip = new HtmlTableCell();
        Tooltip.ID = "Tooltip" + ID;
        Tooltip.Style.Add("display", "block");
}
```

I've tried using a string instead of int for the ID but that doesn't solve it.
Look for the 'onmouseover' in the HTML.

Comment: onmouseover is a client-side event, javascript. can you move the code behind to js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onmouseover is a client-side event, javascript. can you move the code behind to js? if you can, this should do it:

```
...onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(4)"

function DisplayTooltip(tooltipNum) {
    var ele = document.getElementById("Tooltip" + tooltipNum):
    ele.style.display = "block";
}
```

You might have to use 'visibility' instead of display:none if display:none removes the tooltips from the page completely. I think it should be ok though.